# how to concatenate my strings with php in html

Tags: php, html

I know how to concatenate php variable but how about php if else script inside html?
I have used below code:

```
    $output .='
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top"  src="../admin/upload/'. $row['images'].'" width="50px" height="300px" alt="Image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <p><strong> Title : </strong>'. $row['title'].'</p>
            <p><strong> Author : </strong>'. $row['author'].'</p>
            <p><strong> ISBN : </strong>'. $row['isbn'].'</p>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">


            '.$status='';
            if ($row ['status'] == 'Available')
            {
              $status='success';
            }
            else if ($row ['status'] == 'Unavailable')
            {
              $status ='danger';
            }.'

<a href="book_details.php?title='. $row['title'].'&isbn='. $row['isbn'].'"> <button type="button"class="btn btn-'.$status.'">'. $row['status'].'</button></a>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>';
```

How do I concatenate my strings especially when the php if else statement? Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. The cleanest solution would be to put the `if` statement *before* the generation of `$output` i.e.

```
$status = $row ['status'] == 'Available' ? 'success' : 'danger';
$output .= '    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
    ...
          <div class="card-body">
<a href="book_details.php?title='. $row['title'].'&isbn='. $row['isbn'].'"> <button type="button"class="btn btn-'.$status.'">'. $row['status'].'</button></a>
    ...
    </div>';
```

For such large blocks of text, you might want to consider [`heredoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax. See this [demo](https://3v4l.org/rE0h8).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function, and execute it immediately:

```
    $output .='
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <img class="card-img-top"  src="../admin/upload/'. $row['images'].'" width="50px" height="300px" alt="Image">
          <div class="overlay">
            <p><strong> Title : </strong>'. $row['title'].'</p>
            <p><strong> Author : </strong>'. $row['author'].'</p>
            <p><strong> ISBN : </strong>'. $row['isbn'].'</p>

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">


            '.call_user_function(function() use($row) {
            if ($row ['status'] == 'Available')
            {
              return 'success';
            }
            else if ($row ['status'] == 'Unavailable')
            {
              return 'danger';
            }}).'

<a href="book_details.php?title='. $row['title'].'&isbn='. $row['isbn'].'"> <button type="button"class="btn btn-'.$status.'">'. $row['status'].'</button></a>


          </div>
        </div>

      </div>';
```